# Selenium tests(in C#) failing when run from the command line but not VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, selenium, mstest

I'm having an issue with some Selenium tests I have written using C# in visual studio. When I run them(MSTest) from from VS they all pass fine, however if I run the tests from the command line some fail. I've tried a few times and it seems as though the tests fail at random as the number that fail and the individual tests that fail are different each time, this confuses me!. As things stand the tests are failing on our build server and I need to figure out the issue.
Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you be more elaborate? Difficult to make out what exactly the problem is...

Comment: The problem is there seems to be something I've missed/done wrong which is causing my Selenium Unit tests to fail randomly when run from the command line when they all pass fine when run from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The tests are executed faster in VS than in the IDE if you are trying to assert elements of the page that has not been loaded yet. Try adding more pauses or increase the time paused in you test cases.

Is there any pattern to where the test fails although it seems random?

Comment: Do you mean they are executed faster from the command line than VS? At the minute we have waits(60) when searching for elements. From what I have seen there is no obvious pattern to where the tests are failing

Comment: how do you run your tests in VS? Do you have som kind of plugin (Selenium) for VS? what version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I'm using TestDriven.NET and Resharper. If I run the tests with either of these plugins they all pass.

Comment: Do you use the correct driver for the selenium-server/rc ? if so have you tried to update this to the latest stable release?